# Some components of Bootstrap not working with Meteor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

The problem I am having is that only a few of the bootstrap classes are working for me. For example, the `btn` classes are fine, the `container`, `row` classes are also fine. However, the `jumbotron` class, all of the `panel` classes simply are not being styled by bootstrap. I've seen that some bootstrap body tags have some attributes but meteor doesn't allow any attributes on the body tag (I'm not sure if that's the issue).

I'm not exactly sure why some classes are working while others are not. If anyone has an idea of what's going on, it'd be great if they could tell me.

HTML code (Handlebars and Bootstrap classes)

```
<template name="home">
    <div class="container">
        {{> create_poll}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="create_poll">

        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                Create polly!
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="poll-title">
                    <input type="text" id="poll-title" placeholder="Poll title">
                </div>

                <hr>

                <ul class="poll-choices">
                    <li id="poll-choice-1"><input name="choice" type="text" placeholder="Option 1"></li>
                    <li id="poll-choice-2"><input name="choice" type="text" placeholder="Option 2"></li>
                </ul>

                <button id="poll_create" type="Submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Have you checked the styles exist in your css file?

Comment: Why should they exist in my css file? Shouldn't these styles come natively with bootstrap.css?

Comment: They should have you checked they are included?

Comment: Again, the styles are working for some things. Therefore the file is indeed included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current release of Meteor (0.7) only includes bootstrap v2.3.0 (documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)

Bootstrap 2.3 doen't have `jumbotron` (uses `hero-unit`) and doesn't have `panel`

If you want bootstrap 3.0 in your Meteor application - you'll need to add a package that provides it. You can find a bunch of bootstrap packages for Meteor at https://atmosphere.meteor.com/

Comment: Makes sense, totally forgot to look at the version that was being supplied.

Comment: Ah shame I wanted to try jumbotron in a Meteor test app too